# "Downloads are not supported on this device" from Edge Browser

Tags: xbox-series-x-series-s

I get this error "Downloads werden auf diesem Gerät nicht unterstützt", translation "Downloads are not supported on this device".

I wish to install a Kodi plugin.

[image]

Comment: Not surprising. Downloads, and the file explorer were discontinued during the life span of the XB1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Downloads are indeed unsupported on Xbox](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/hardware-network/console/use-microsoft-edge-on-xbox):

> ###### Things to keep in mind:
>
> - Some features that exist on other versions of Edge (like **downloads** or browser extensions) are **not supported on the console version of the browser**.

The only way to install apps on the Xbox is through the Xbox App Store or through the app itself (if it supports it).